# delphi convert.exe: convert compiled delphi dfm files to text files, header signature issue

Tags: delphi

I'm using the convert.exe tool of delphi to convert dfm files into txt files to translate them and then convert them back to compiled dfm.

Delphi Form Conversion Utility Version 7.1
Copyright (c) 1995-2014 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.

convert -t -i file.dfm on the command line generates a file.dfm with the file decompiled plain text
convert -b -i file.dfm on the command line generates a binary compiled file.dfm

the issue I'm having seems to be related with the header, on hexa editor the dfm file to convert to text file starts with TPF0 signature and when I convert it to text it does nothing.
if I use convert.exe to convert a file.dfm (text format) to a binary dfm It seems that it's adding extra headers that my files doesn't have actually it adds this "FF 0A 00 54 46 4F 52 4D 31 00 30 10 3C 01 00 00"
the files that have this extra signature on the top of TPF0 are actually correctly converted back and forth...
It's probably related to the fact that the compiled dfm files are too old, that's why I went install a delphi v7 to get an old convert.exe

Delphi Form Conversion Utility Version 5.0
Copyright (c) 1995,99 Inprise Corporation

but still same issue...
do I have to add manually a fake extra header to have it work ? what version do I need to go back to handle that dfm version that starts only with TPF0

Thanks

Comment: Removed the C/C# tags (Delphi has never supported either of those languages) and C++ (because you don't mention C++ Builder in your question at all). Please use only tags that apply to your actual question instead of just randomly adding them because they sound familiar.

Comment: There is no header in a .DFM file, AFAICT. Are you sure you're not trying to run it against a .DCU? I use Convert.exe all the time to convert some older project .DFM files to text, and often use the one from XE7 on old Delphi 7/2007 .DFM files without any issue. .DFM files do not have the TP0 signature; that's in compiled .DCU files.

Comment: It's text or binary format, contains the same information, there's no compilation.

Comment: By default .dfm files are text

Comment: @David: But not in older versions of Delphi, which is why convert.exe exists. And opening a binary .DFM in a newer version of Delphi does not automatically convert it to text.

Comment: @Ken Default changed to text in D5 or D6 I think

Comment: @David: Which, as I said, means that the default hasn't always been text .dfms. :-) I have one app here that is evolved since Delphi 2 (currently in D2007) that still has binary .dfms, the developer sees no need to change them, and I frequently have to convert them in order to see the contents from a text editor to find out what property values are (eg., database names in a datamodule).

Comment: @Ken I suppose my point is that if user would use the default then there would be no need for any conversion.

Comment: The header OP mentions is the `...TFORM1.0.....` section in the binary dfm file. Afaik, it's always been there, I have no idea why it would be missing in OP's binary dfm. By any chance, are you using SourceSafe? I remember having trouble with binary dfm files stored in SourceSafe as text.

Comment: You could try `ObjectResourceToText` or if that doesn't work because of the missing header? try `ObjectBinaryToText`. See  http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.Classes.ObjectResourceToText